# Not getting any data in $_POST variable

Tags: php, post, http-post

I have a strange issue on the live server, I have same site in 3 different servers and in one of the Godaddy server I am not able to get the data in $_POST variable. It is always showing blank array.

I have overwrite the values of some PHP variables in php.ini file and all new values are set in the phpinfo as well.

```
memory_limit=512M 
max_input_vars=10000
upload_max_filesize=125M
post_max_size=1024M
max_execution_time=180000
```

But still not able to get values in post data. I have many input fields in my form but I think `max_input_vars` should fix it but that doesn't help.

I have SSL on the live server.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please, add all relevant scripts to that problem!

Comment: Is it working when adding a new form with only a small amount of inputfields?

Comment: yes is working for new form. I have dynamic form where we are creating multiple input fields. So having issue with the form which has many input fields

Comment: Do some testing. Start with a very basic form, does it work? Go on from there. More so, if the basic form doesn't work, you would have a good question. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KIKOSoftware All other forms are working fine and also new form is working. I have one dynamic CMS website. When I try to edit one form where I have too many input fields in that case I am getting this issue.

Comment: I've been on SO too long, but all is relative, so please quantify your: 'I have too many input fields'. Otherwise the only solution I can give you is: 'Reduce the number of input fields'.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Input fields are around 1200+. I have something like this [link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Dynamically-Add-More-Form-Fields-czMore/) where you can add as much as possible input fields you want in one form.

Comment: That's a lot of fields. With that many fields I would not post them all at once, I would simply post changed made by the user by AJAX. There are two advantages: The user doesn't stand to loose many changes when something goods badly wrong, and the amount of data that is updated each time is relatively small. I do realize that this doesn't help you much with your current problem, but we simply cannot know what's wrong due to too much missing information.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with the one sample script and found that this is the issue with the server itself, as they allowed to overwrite values by php.ini file but it is not actually taking any effect.